# Format Tweets just like the Twitter Archive using R

Tags: python, r, csv, tweepy

I wanted to know how to format a CSV file just like the Twitter archive does so that R does not have a problem reading it (ran into a bunch of problems with it with no solutions). The Twitter archive is of a user timeline and my CSV (on which I'll be performing sentiment analysis using R) is of a search result containing Tweets.

Sample of the Twitter archive

```
"tweet_id","in_reply_to_status_id","in_reply_to_user_id","timestamp","source","text","retweeted_status_id","retweeted_status_user_id","retweeted_status_timestamp","expanded_urls"
"81423594213695488","","","2016-12-29 14:18:08 +0000","<a href=""http://twitter.com/download/android"" rel=""nofollow"">Twitter for Android</a>","RT @SwiftOnSecurity: We're going to tell kids that laptops used to store data on tiny mirrors spinning @ 7200rpm and they're going to think…","814187405175570432","2436389418","2016-12-28 19:12:58 +0000",""
"876926582348550143","","","2016-12-22 13:29:16 +0000","<a href=""http://twitter.com/download/android"" rel=""nofollow"">Twitter for Android</a>","RT @MKBHD: Shout-out to everyone going home and becoming family tech support for the holidays","811910809521680384","29873662","2016-12-22 12:26:36 +0000",""
```

What I've managed to make so far

```
"text"
b'RT @notCORYGREGORY: when hillary uses a private email server asking how to print recipes vs when trump takes healthcare from 20+ million am\xe2\x80\xa6'
b'RT @Salon: Germany is giving up on President Trump'
```

How I do it in Python:

```
csvFile = open('tweets.csv', 'a')
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=',')

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
    q="trump",
    rpp=100,
    result_type="recent",
    include_entities=True,
    lang="en").items(5):
        print (tweet.text)
        csvWriter.writerow([tweet.text.encode('utf-8')])

csvFile.close()
```

I'm open to solutions in R

Comment: There is a package in R that lets you download tweets, its called twitteR. You can also download tweets from there based on date and language and later write it as csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not fully understand your question, but you may want to have a look at the twitteR library in R, especially for the function "twListToDF". If you combine it with write.csv, you can right the tweets you have collected in a csv format, that R is also able to read.

```
write.csv(twListToDF(your_tweets), file="your_tweets.csv")
```